# Install npmbox on a windows offline machine

Tags: bash, npm

I'm trying to install `npmbox` on an offline machine running `windows` server.

According to the docs, after creating `npmbox.npmbox` on an online machine, I have to move to the offline one, copy the file, and run `tar -xvfo npmbox.npmbox`.
I can't use the `-o` option, so If I remove it I can move on.

Afterwards, running `tar -xvf npmbox.npmbox` I run

```
npm install --global --cache ./.npmbox-cache --optional --no-registry --fetch-retries 0 --fetch-retry-factor 0 --fetch-retry-mintimeout 1 --fetch-retry-maxtimeout 2 npmbox
```

And this error pops.

```
TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not object
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Done, I'll add the answer as soon as system allows me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5509) that helped me solve my problem.

Just change `--no-registry` with `--cache-min 999999` and that should install from cache straight forward.

Comment: `--cache-min 999999` actually.